# Resize image and keep aspect ratio

Tags: vb.net, image, algorithm, resize, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make zoom in/out buttons, but for whatever reason I just can't figure out how to maintain the aspect ratio and resize the image by - say 90% or 110%

The issue is that I'm trying to make it so that when you click the zoom out button 4 times, then click the zoom in button 4 times, the image would be its original size. There's no defined width since I'm trying to make the new width be 90%/110% of the existing width, but  obviously multiplying by 0.9 and 1.1 doesn't do that correctly.

I currently have the following code..

```
    Dim source As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
    Dim NewWidth As Integer = source.Width * 0.9
    Dim NewHeight As Integer = NewWidth * (source.Height / source.Width)
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure I'm just over-thinking it again, but some guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: For you NewHeight just do the same you did with NewWidth. It's simpler  to understand. `NewHeight = source.Height * 0.9`

Comment: Why not just `Dim NewHeight As Integer = source.Height * 0.9`?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it didn't work because (100*0.9)*1.1 != 100, that's the issue.

Comment: Did you consider multiplying by 1.1 when zooming in and dividing by 1.1 when zooming out? 
Specifically, 1/1.1 = 0.909090...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to begin each resize operation with a copy of the *original* image.  Have your buttons represent the total zoom factor (so say add 0.1 zoom for the + and subtract 0.1 zoom for the -).

You want to start with the original image each time because otherwise successive operations will quickly distort the image due to the interpolation inherent in zooming in and out.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that. I'll write something up really quick and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

My function actually works (resx and resy are desidered size):

```
Public Function ScaleImage(ByVal p As PictureBox, ByRef i As Bitmap, resx As Integer, resy As Integer) As Image
    Dim returnedBMP As Image = Nothing

    If i.Height >= resy Then
        Dim diff As Integer = i.Height - p.Height
        Dim diffw As Integer = i.Width - p.Width
        Dim imageSize As Size = i.Size
        Dim aspectRatio As Double = i.Height / i.Width
        Dim new_w = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(resy / aspectRatio))

        If i.Width >= resx Then
            Dim Resized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(i, New Size(new_w, resy))
            i = Resized
            returnedBMP = Resized
        Else
            Dim Resized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(i, New Size(i.Width, resy))
            i = Resized
            returnedBMP = Resized
        End If
    End If

    Return returnedBMP
End Function
```